# Make a colorbar for RGB data?

Tags: python, colorbar

I got data that is made based on a 3 channels, which are red in as RGB, this means that the color bar would have to circle between all 3 colors to show all possible shades Is there a simple way of doing this?

Here is an example. Red is left enhanced, blue right enhanced and green centrally enhanced. (it is looking at spectral features.) This means that Red+Blue (= Purple) would be right and central enhanced and weak in left. etc.

I need a way to show that properly with a colorbar of sorts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood what is your expected result. I'm providing a temporary answer anyway so that you can eventually point me to the right direction.
This is an example colorbar made with numpy arrays:

[image]

The code I used to generate it is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Initialize an empty array that matches opencv ranges for hsv images:
#   hue (cylinder 180°) 0-179 (multiplied by 10 to "stretch" horizontally)
#   saturation is fixed at 254
#   value (0-254)
bar = np.ndarray([255,1800,3], dtype="uint8")
for x in range(1800):
    for y in range(255):
        bar[y,x,0] = int(x/10)
        bar[y,x,1] = 254
        bar[y,x,2] = y
#Convert to BGR (opencv standard instead of rgb)
bgr = cv2.cvtColor(bar, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
cv2.imshow('Colorbar', bgr)
cv2.waitKey()
```